# Is there a common "curriculum" for children of noble houses in Westeros?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

As an *spin-off* of [What is the education system like in Westeros?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/87783/32339) where we learn that

- Not all houses have *maesters*. If a Maester cannot be contracted, then the Lord of the house will often find someone else to teach his children.
- Once a noble house has made arrangements with their Maester as to the appropriate subjects for their children, the Maester will generally tutor the children as needed, using a scheduled curriculum.

I wonder what they are normally taught.

I understand that whatever they are taught, differs greatly depending on gender (since very different things are expected from each). From the TV show, I seem to remember seeing the Starks learning to use swords (or to fight), bow and arrows and learning heraldry (learning about the other noble houses). Probably riding and reading and writing are taught too.

What is the usual curriculum for the children of noble houses in Westeros?

Comment: From other questions, it seems that the nobility of westeros is fairly literate, so that is probably one part of the common curriculum

Comment: How is this question different?

Comment: @Skooba I think you mean [Emmentaller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emmental_cheese)

Comment: @Möoz, the linked question is "**How** do they learn" and surprisingly it does not address "**what** do they actually learn". None of the answers in that question cover this and I didn't think it would be "good citizenship" modifying that question to try to get my answer there. Thus, I spinned off this question, hoping I would learn what are the highborn (boys and girls) actually taught. Also, in the linked question's answer stress is in the **maesters** only, but I doubt they would teach to fight, ride, sew or dance. Also, there's room for detail (they learn to fight with _which_ weapons?).

Answer (score 3):

Since you are looking an answer for a noble house, I think we can use the example of [Young Griff](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aegon_Targaryen_(son_of_Rhaegar)):

- **Martial arts**

  > When the bacon was gone, Duck punched Young Griff in the shoulder. "Time to raise some bruises. Swords today, I think."
  >
  > "Swords?" Young Griff grinned. "Swords will be sweet."
  >
  > *A Dance with Dragons - Tyrion IV*
- **Theology**

  > Whilst Young Griff went off with Septa Lemore to be instructed in the mysteries of the Faith, Tyrion stripped off the wet clothes and donned dry ones.
  >
  > *A Dance with Dragons - Tyrion IV*
- **Languages, Geometry, History**

  > The lesson began with languages. Young Griff spoke the Common Tongue as if he had been born to it, and was fluent in High Valyrian, the low dialects of Pentos, Tyrosh, Myr, and Lys, and the trade talk of sailors. The Volantene dialect was as new to him as it was to Tyrion, so every day they learned a few more words whilst Haldon corrected their mistakes. Meereenese was harder; its roots were Valyrian as well, but the tree had been grafted onto the harsh, ugly tongue of Old Ghis. "You need a bee up your nose to speak Ghiscari properly," Tyrion complained. Young Griff laughed, but the Halfmaester only said, "Again." The boy obeyed, though he rolled his eyes along with his zzzs this time. He has a better ear than me, Tyrion was forced to admit, though I'll wager my tongue is still more nimble.
  >
  > Geometry followed languages. There the boy was less adroit, but Haldon was a patient teacher, and Tyrion was able to make himself of use as well. He had learned the mysteries of squares and circles and triangles from his father's maesters at Casterly Rock, and they came back more quickly than he would have thought.
  >
  > By the time they turned to history, Young Griff was growing restive.
  >
  > *A Dance with Dragons - Tyrion IV*

Which all in all is a fairly complete education!

> Tyrion watched with mismatched eyes, and said, "The boy is bright. You have done well by him. Half the lords in Westeros are not so learned, sad to say. Languages, history, songs, sums … a heady stew for some sellsword's son."
>
> *A Dance with Dragons - Tyrion IV*

---

We can see this earlier in the series as well with the Stark children learning from Maester Luwin (specifically Bran learning heraldry), Ser Rodrick Cassel (teaching the boys in arms), and Septa Mordane (teaching Sansa and Arya sewing, among other things).

Comment: There is no curriculum though: *Half the lords in Westeros are not so learned*

Comment: I don't know about languages. From Joffrey's wedding: "A haunting ballad of two dying lovers amidst the Doom of Valyria might have pleased the hall more if Collio had not sung it in High Valyrian, which most of the guests could not speak."

Comment: And in general the education of Young Griff might be a poor example. He was not being raised to be lord of some holdfast, he was raised to rule the entire Seven Kingdoms.

Comment: @TenthJustice good thing the OP was asking about the "*children of noble houses in Westeros?*" and not some Landed Knight.